# How to access context information in an Xtext validator?

Tags: java, xtext

I have an Xtext grammar that does something like this:

```
Model:
  (names += Name)*
  (rules += Rule)*
;

Rule:
  'rule' ruleName = ID;

Name:
  name = ID+;

terminal ID:
  ('a'..'z')+;
```

I want to validate the `ruleName` has been declared in the names block. I can access the rule name itself in the `JavaValidator` like this:

```
@Check
public void checkName(Rule rule) {
  rule.getName(); // how to compare to names without access to Model object?
}
```

but I cannot access the `names` field from `Model`. How do I do that in the `JavaValidator`?

Comment: Sorry if the example grammar doesn't compile, I just wrote it as an example. The main idea should be clear though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternatively `(Model)rule.eContainer()` should give you the model

Answer (score 0):

If it is not mandatory for you to define `Name` as terminal, then consider using [cross-references](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/2_1_0/020-grammar-language.php#cross_reference):

```
grammar org.example.YourDSL
  with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate secrets "http://www.example.org/yourdsl"

Model:
  (names += Name)*
  (rules += Rule)*
;

Name:
  name=ID; // name of the property is important!
Rule:
  'rule' name=[Name];

// Override ID from org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
terminal ID:
  ('a'..'z')+;
```

Comment: This isn't what I mean, but I see how you would think that. I've edited my grammar for clarity.